# build otp_src_22.3-erlang on my linux, report the err:make: tertiary_bootstrap_build Error 2

Tags: makefile, build, erlang, snmp, erlang-otp

I must build erlang on a mini REDHAT6.5. because of some case,I have to use the /data/matt to build !
I have build openssl\ jdk \unixODBC2 \pcre8 \ net-snmp --without-perl ...
the configure command:

```
otp_src_22.3]$ ./configure --prefix=/data/matt/matt_env/erlang24  LDFLAGS="-L/data/matt/matt_env/ncurses6/lib -L/data/matt/matt_env/openssl/lib -L/data/matt/matt_env/zlib/lib -L/data/matt/matt_env/unixODBC2/lib -L/data/matt/matt_env/unixODBC2/lib -L/data/matt/matt_env/pcre8/lib -L/data/matt/matt_env/net-snmp/lib"  --with-ssl=/data/matt/matt_env/openssl --with-PACKAGE=/data/matt/matt_env/zlib/lib/pkgconfig --with-PACKAGE=/data/matt/matt_env/pcre8/lib/pkgconfig --without-termcap CFLAGS="-O -I/data/matt/matt_env/unixODBC2/include -I/data/matt/matt_env/net-snmp/include/net-snmp/" --with-odbc=/data/matt/matt_env/unixODBC2/lib
```

when I run make,get the error:

```
ERLC   ../../ebin/snmp_shadow_table.beam
Failed to create poll thread
Failed to create scheduler thread 7, error = 11
Failed to create dirty io scheduler thread 6, error = 11
Failed to create dirty io scheduler thread 2, error = 11
Failed to create poll thread
Failed to create scheduler thread 2, error = 11
Failed to create dirty cpu scheduler thread 0, error = 11
/bin/sh: line 1: 17230 Aborted                 (core dumped) erlc -W +debug_info -DUSE_ESOCK=true -pa /data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/snmp/ebin -I../../include -I../misc -Dversion=\"5.5\" +'{parse_transform,sys_pre_attributes}' +'{attribute,insert,app_vsn,"snmp-5.5"}' -I/data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/stdlib -Ddefault_verbosity=silence -o../../ebin snmpa_symbolic_store.erl
make[5]: *** [../../ebin/snmpa_symbolic_store.beam] Error 134
make[5]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/bin/sh: line 1: 16894 Aborted                 erlc -W +debug_info -DUSE_ESOCK=true -pa /data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/snmp/ebin -I../../include -I../misc -Dversion=\"5.5\" +'{parse_transform,sys_pre_attributes}' +'{attribute,insert,app_vsn,"snmp-5.5"}' -I/data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/stdlib -Ddefault_verbosity=silence -o../../ebin snmpa_agent.erl
make[5]: *** [../../ebin/snmpa_agent.beam] Error 134
/bin/sh: line 1: 17056 Aborted                 erlc -W +debug_info -DUSE_ESOCK=true -pa /data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/snmp/ebin -I../../include -I../misc -Dversion=\"5.5\" +'{parse_transform,sys_pre_attributes}' +'{attribute,insert,app_vsn,"snmp-5.5"}' -I/data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/stdlib -Ddefault_verbosity=silence -o../../ebin snmpa_mib_storage_dets.erl
make[5]: *** [../../ebin/snmpa_mib_storage_dets.beam] Error 134
/bin/sh: line 1: 16875 Aborted                 (core dumped) erlc -W +debug_info -DUSE_ESOCK=true -pa /data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/snmp/ebin -I../../include -I../misc -Dversion=\"5.5\" +'{parse_transform,sys_pre_attributes}' +'{attribute,insert,app_vsn,"snmp-5.5"}' -I/data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/stdlib -Ddefault_verbosity=silence -o../../ebin snmp_target_mib.erl
make[5]: *** [../../ebin/snmp_target_mib.beam] Error 134
/bin/sh: line 1: 17334 Aborted                 (core dumped) erlc -W +debug_info -DUSE_ESOCK=true -pa /data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/snmp/ebin -I../../include -I../misc -Dversion=\"5.5\" +'{parse_transform,sys_pre_attributes}' +'{attribute,insert,app_vsn,"snmp-5.5"}' -I/data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/stdlib -Ddefault_verbosity=silence -o../../ebin snmpa_trap.erl
make[5]: *** [../../ebin/snmpa_trap.beam] Error 134
Failed to create dirty io scheduler thread 4, error = 11
Failed to create dirty cpu scheduler thread 0, error = 11
Failed to create dirty cpu scheduler thread 6, error = 11
Failed to create dirty io scheduler thread 4, error = 11
Failed to create dirty io scheduler thread 5, error = 11
/bin/sh: line 1: 17143 Aborted                 erlc -W +debug_info -DUSE_ESOCK=true -pa /data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/snmp/ebin -I../../include -I../misc -Dversion=\"5.5\" +'{parse_transform,sys_pre_attributes}' +'{attribute,insert,app_vsn,"snmp-5.5"}' -I/data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/stdlib -Ddefault_verbosity=silence -o../../ebin snmpa_set.erl
make[5]: *** [../../ebin/snmpa_set.beam] Error 134
/bin/sh: line 1: 17255 Aborted                 erlc -W +debug_info -DUSE_ESOCK=true -pa /data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/snmp/ebin -I../../include -I../misc -Dversion=\"5.5\" +'{parse_transform,sys_pre_attributes}' +'{attribute,insert,app_vsn,"snmp-5.5"}' -I/data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/stdlib -Ddefault_verbosity=silence -o../../ebin snmpa_target_cache.erl
make[5]: *** [../../ebin/snmpa_target_cache.beam] Error 134
/bin/sh: line 1: 17203 Aborted                 (core dumped) erlc -W +debug_info -DUSE_ESOCK=true -pa /data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/snmp/ebin -I../../include -I../misc -Dversion=\"5.5\" +'{parse_transform,sys_pre_attributes}' +'{attribute,insert,app_vsn,"snmp-5.5"}' -I/data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/stdlib -Ddefault_verbosity=silence -o../../ebin snmpa_supervisor.erl
make[5]: *** [../../ebin/snmpa_supervisor.beam] Error 134
/bin/sh: line 1: 17228 Aborted                 (core dumped) erlc -W +debug_info -DUSE_ESOCK=true -pa /data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/snmp/ebin -I../../include -I../misc -Dversion=\"5.5\" +'{parse_transform,sys_pre_attributes}' +'{attribute,insert,app_vsn,"snmp-5.5"}' -I/data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/stdlib -Ddefault_verbosity=silence -o../../ebin snmpa_svbl.erl
make[5]: *** [../../ebin/snmpa_svbl.beam] Error 134
/bin/sh: line 1: 17362 Aborted                 (core dumped) erlc -W +debug_info -DUSE_ESOCK=true -pa /data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/snmp/ebin -I../../include -I../misc -Dversion=\"5.5\" +'{parse_transform,sys_pre_attributes}' +'{attribute,insert,app_vsn,"snmp-5.5"}' -I/data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/stdlib -Ddefault_verbosity=silence -o../../ebin snmpa_vacm.erl
make[5]: *** [../../ebin/snmpa_vacm.beam] Error 134
/bin/sh: line 1: 17070 Aborted                 erlc -W +debug_info -DUSE_ESOCK=true -pa /data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/snmp/ebin -I../../include -I../misc -Dversion=\"5.5\" +'{parse_transform,sys_pre_attributes}' +'{attribute,insert,app_vsn,"snmp-5.5"}' -I/data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/stdlib -Ddefault_verbosity=silence -o../../ebin snmpa_mib.erl
make[5]: *** [../../ebin/snmpa_mib.beam] Error 134
Failed to create dirty cpu scheduler thread 1, error = 11
Failed to create poll thread
Failed to create dirty cpu scheduler thread 7, error = 11
Failed to create dirty cpu scheduler thread 3, error = 11
/bin/sh: line 1: 17572 Aborted                 erlc -W +debug_info -DUSE_ESOCK=true -pa /data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/snmp/ebin -I../../include -I../misc -Dversion=\"5.5\" +'{parse_transform,sys_pre_attributes}' +'{attribute,insert,app_vsn,"snmp-5.5"}' -I/data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/stdlib -Ddefault_verbosity=silence -o../../ebin snmp_generic_mnesia.erl
make[5]: *** [../../ebin/snmp_generic_mnesia.beam] Error 134
/bin/sh: line 1: 17596 Aborted                 (core dumped) erlc -W +debug_info -DUSE_ESOCK=true -pa /data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/snmp/ebin -I../../include -I../misc -Dversion=\"5.5\" +'{parse_transform,sys_pre_attributes}' +'{attribute,insert,app_vsn,"snmp-5.5"}' -I/data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/stdlib -Ddefault_verbosity=silence -o../../ebin snmp_index.erl
make[5]: *** [../../ebin/snmp_index.beam] Error 134
/bin/sh: line 1: 17350 Aborted                 (core dumped) erlc -W +debug_info -DUSE_ESOCK=true -pa /data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/snmp/ebin -I../../include -I../misc -Dversion=\"5.5\" +'{parse_transform,sys_pre_attributes}' +'{attribute,insert,app_vsn,"snmp-5.5"}' -I/data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/stdlib -Ddefault_verbosity=silence -o../../ebin snmpa_usm.erl
make[5]: *** [../../ebin/snmpa_usm.beam] Error 134
/bin/sh: line 1: 17050 Aborted                 (core dumped) erlc -W +debug_info -DUSE_ESOCK=true -pa /data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/snmp/ebin -I../../include -I../misc -Dversion=\"5.5\" +'{parse_transform,sys_pre_attributes}' +'{attribute,insert,app_vsn,"snmp-5.5"}' -I/data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/stdlib -Ddefault_verbosity=silence -o../../ebin snmpa_mib_storage_ets.erl
make[5]: *** [../../ebin/snmpa_mib_storage_ets.beam] Error 134
/bin/sh: line 1: 17045 Aborted                 (core dumped) erlc -W +debug_info -DUSE_ESOCK=true -pa /data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/snmp/ebin -I../../include -I../misc -Dversion=\"5.5\" +'{parse_transform,sys_pre_attributes}' +'{attribute,insert,app_vsn,"snmp-5.5"}' -I/data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/stdlib -Ddefault_verbosity=silence -o../../ebin snmpa_local_db.erl
make[5]: *** [../../ebin/snmpa_local_db.beam] Error 134
make[5]: Leaving directory `/data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/snmp/src/agent'
make[4]: *** [opt] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/snmp/src/agent'
make[3]: *** [opt] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/snmp/src'
make[2]: *** [opt] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib/snmp'
make[1]: *** [opt] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/data/matt/matt_env/otp_src_22.3/lib'
make: *** [tertiary_bootstrap_build] Error 2
```

the snmp is build with 5.7, and the system there is a 5.5 of snmp self.
can help me find how can I slove the  err?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either raise the limit of the number of threads/processes allowed to be created by the user or limit the number of threads created.

It seems like you are running parallel make, I would suggest disabling that and see if that is enough.

Otherwise you can limit the number of schedulers created by setting ERL_FLAGS to ‘+S 1’

Comment: Ok! I'm trying it ! :-) ,thanks!

Comment: I use one thread! Now , I get the err: 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lodbc.  ：0， I had used export ODBC_LIB=-L"/data/matt/matt_env/unixODBC2/lib" and export ODBC_INCLUDE="-I/data/matt/matt_env/unixODBC2/include".

Comment: "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/matt/matt_env/ncurses6/lib:/data/matt/matt_env/openssl/lib:/data/matt/matt_env/zlib/lib:/data/matt/matt_env/unixODBC2/lib:/data/matt/matt_env/pcre8/lib:/lib:/lib64"  -- no useful :-[